# select2 from append not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I'm using the select2 plugin from http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/.

I've got a form where I can add a new line. What I do is get the html from the previous line and append it to my form.

So this worked and the select2 is also added to the new line. The problem is when I click on the select 2 element nothing happened.

Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: Can you create jsfiddle for it?

Comment: you might have to do some refreshing (destroy, then initial again) create a http://jsfiddle.net so we can help you

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/979nG/4/ This is what I'm trying to do...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason it won't work the way you're doing it is because copying the HTML won't copy any event handlers or other select2 functionality.

To do that, as mentioned in the comments, we'll need to first destroy the original select2, clone its DOM elements, then reinitialise the original select2 and then initialise the copy.

It's probably easier to factor out the initialisation to a helper function, like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {        

    var $selectParent = $('#select-parent'),
        $copy;

    init($selectParent);

    $("#duplicate").click(function() {

        $selectParent.select2('destroy');

        var $copy = $selectParent.clone();
        $(".form").append($copy);

        init($selectParent);
        init($copy);

    });
});

function init($elem) {
    $elem.select2({
        minimumResultsForSearch: -1,
        width: 'resolve'
    });   
}
```

Check this [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/979nG/5/)